# Billing is not enabling in Google App Engine account

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, billing

I went through the steps of "Enable Billing" 3 times in the past 3 days and after everytime I start the enable billing on my GAE python app it tells me billing is activating then I come back and it asks me to enable billing...

So I go through the process again, enter my credit card (I've tried switching cards - my cards work elsewhere, nothing is wrong with them).

On the "Activating billing" page it says it'll take up to 15 minutes, I read elsewhere it could take 30 minutes to activate billing.

The reason this is a problem is my app is live but I have reached the db read quota for the free account.

Does anyone have any idea, esp the google people, why my app billing isn't enabling. I need to fix this ASAP, this app is for a client.. I'm going to temporarily stop db reads from the site in my code so people can at least access the content.

Would really, really appreciate your help!!!

Note - I never got any errors of charges failing or anything... I'm just prompted to click the enable billing button again..

Comment: Have you tried taking this up with the Google app engine team? I think thats the first place you need to go.

Comment: I've tried filling any and every form I could find for GAE and have even tried to spin up other GAE app IDs and see if I can at least enable billing on them. Do know of any app-engine dedicated way for GAE support. I also read that their support team has shifted here to stack overflow...

Comment: This is what I could find https://cloud.google.com/contact, also try getting in touch with them on Google plus

Comment: Thanks, I just filled out their form.. have you ever enabled billing on an app? and in general how long did you have to wait..?

Comment: No I have never reached the point where I had to set up billing but just doing a quick search into their cloud FAQs it says billing can sometimes take up to 3 days so maybe that is the issue you are having have a look here it explains how to check on the status of your order https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/billing#delayed

Answer (score 0):

The support team can help with some billing-related requests, but they'll need your application id. Please fill out the form here: http://support.google.com/code/bin/request.py?hl=en&contact_type=cloud_platform_billing&ctx=go